# I have to triple tap everything on Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I don't know how the settings were changed; my young daughter may have done it. Also, I just got the new update this morning. I have to touch, then double tap every time. Also, there is a yellow line around the screen and everthimg. I've checked all settings I know of, but I can't reverse this.

Comment: It would be helpful to at least know the Android version you're running. The color of your line irritates me, but could it be you've got some developer's options enabled?

Comment: It just updated probably icecream sandwich.  Seems like a developers option, but when I go into settings, It seems like ive tried to change relevent options but nothing changes what I have.  I have drop box set up.  If I hard reset will I still have all my pictures os should I back it all up on usb or micro sd card?

Comment: A backup never hurts. A factory reset will remove all user data/apps on the device, so when considering that you should make sure havin everything backed up (best even copy the sd card contents to your computer). But first check in *Settings -> Development*, there was one setting causing such a frame.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  I finally found it.. My daughter must have been in the accessibiltiy settings.  She had the talk back on.  But I didnt realize because she also had turn off all sounds on.  I dont know how that makes the tapping weird, but is fixed now.  Grrrr!  Kids.... Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome, Sheryl! Would you mind to write up a summary, answering your own question? This would help future visitors if encountering the same problem. A short step-by-step description would be fine; if you've got screenshots to include, simply put in the links to them and ping me for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Sheryl found the answer herself. Quoting [her comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37203/i-have-to-triple-tap-everything-on-galaxy-tab-10-1#comment48968_37203):

> I finally found it.. My daughter must have been in the accessibiltiy settings. She had the talk back on. But I didnt realize because she also had turn off all sounds on. I dont know how that makes the tapping weird, but is fixed now.

If one has a similar effect (e.g. red borders shown), and it's not the *accessibility settings*, another place to look for is the *development settings*, which also has switches to highlight certain areas for "developer feedback" when testing an app.

Answer (score 0):

Settings>Accessibility>Magnification Gestures.

I actually set this setting on myself so I could zoom into the screen whenever and where ever I wanted and when I did this, a yellow/orange line would border the screen to let me know I was in that magnification. However, I've been noticing a glitch with this tablet that's happening more frequently and this is whenever my finger is on the screen, all of a sudden it'll zoom in as if I triple tapped when I never took my finger off the screen. Well, I can't seem to do anything about the glitch so I wanted to stop the triple-tap-to-zoom feature just that I forgot how I turned it on. This post that I am replying to helped me figure out how to change it back. However, the previous answer wasn't very clear to me. I finally figured it out so I've decided to give the answer more clear for anyone that may have this problem in the future. Thank you. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Galaxy S5 which drove me totally crazy.  It was stuck in the talk back mode and required a tap followed by a quick double tap before any selection was activated.

None of the info I found online helped.  I finally tried going to Accesibility → Hearing and noticed that Hearing aids was checked.

So I set turn off all sounds and unchecked hearing aids and the talk back stopped and the triple tapping ended.  I went back in and set hearing aids and it still worked just fine.

I know, it doesn't make sense but that is what happened.  My software version `G900PVPU1B0A6`, hardware versioin `G900P04`.

Answer (score 0):

in Setting, type accessibility, click Filter accessibility event logging> Explore by Touch, turn this off

this is for my S10, the talk back and triple tapping need to be turned off separately.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings >> accessibillity >> explore by touch
see if that is turned on or off, if its on , **turn it off**  and everything will be normal.